# Get part of string to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take value from beginning of input to cursor. val() return whole string. How can I only this part which I`m interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selectionStart` to get the caret position, so:

```
var caretpos = $('input').prop('selectionStart');
var value = $('input').val().substring(0, caretpos);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zzkaw/

Actually, as the name implies, `selectionStart` is used for selections. However, if there is no selection, `selectionStart === selectionEnd`, and the values represent the caret position.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're dealing with `<input type="text">` with no possibility of line breaks, the following will work. Unfortunately, IE < 9 doesn't have the sensible `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties that other browsers have so you have to faff around with `TextRange`s.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UcnCc/

Code:

```
function getTextToCaret(input) {
    var caretPos = 0;
    if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
        caretPos = input.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        input.focus();
        var textRange = input.createTextRange();
        var selRange = document.selection.createRange();
        textRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selRange);
        caretPos = textRange.text.length;
    }
    return input.value.slice(0, caretPos);
}
```